# Is there a way to find a container by it's environment variables on Portainer?

Tags: search, portainer

The company I work on uses portainer to organize the containers. We're having a problem with a project that seems to be down, but we can't find its container because there are just too many. Only thing I know about the container is the URL of the website, which is a Env variable.

Is there a way to do a search on the containers list where I could use the specific Env variable to find it or is it just simple container name search?